# how to show a particular alphabet item of array in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have two arrays one for alphabets and second for tags..
So i want to show only same alphabets items in that particular alphabet category
**example** -- **apple has to come in A category and zoo has to come in Z category...**

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/4dGxn/149/

**html**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="alp in alpha">
  <h2>{{alp}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**angular**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

  $scope.tags = ["apple", "dog", "cat", "dad", "baby", "zoo", "love", "hate", "rat", "room", "home", "age", "bad"];

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

  $scope.tags = ["apple", "dog", "cat", "dad", "baby", "zoo", "love", "hate", "rat", "room", "home", "age", "bad"];

  $scope.f = function(alp) {
    return function(tag) {
      return tag[0] == alp;
    } 
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="alp in alpha">
  <h2>{{alp}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags | filter:f(alp)">{{tag}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is perfect.. doesnt load the other elements.. +1

Answer (score 8):

You can use `str.startsWith` to check if element starts with a particular character
So in your example:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="alp in alpha">
  <h2>{{alp}}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-show="{{tag.startsWith(alp)}}">{{tag}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the wirking [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dGxn/150/)

Comment: plus 1 perfect answer.

Comment: This will add all tags under each alpha in hidden state, results in adding more html li elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom filters, in the second ng-repeat.

Using ng-show will create unwanted dom elements in alpha group.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
 
  $scope.alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p","q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  
  $scope.tags = ["apple", "dog", "cat", "dad", "baby", "zoo", "love", "hate", "rat", "room", "home", "age", "bad"];

 
}]);

app.filter('myfilter', function(){
    return function(input, text){
        // I recommend to use underscore lib for old browser.
        return input.filter(function(item){
            // I recommend to use standard regex for old browser.
            return item.startsWith(text);
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

<div class="form-group" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="alp in alpha">
  <h2>{{alp}}</h2>
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="tag in tags | myfilter:alp">{{tag}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```